# py2app producing no executable. Segmentation fault: 11

Tags: python, py2app

I'm trying to create a mac executable file using `py2app` but I'm getting a `Segmentation fault: 11` error.

I have a very simple app called `basic_app.py` which prints out 'Hi there!'. And I've already created `setup.py` using the command `py2applet --make-setup basic_app.py`.

When I try to create the `build` and `dist` folders using the command `python setup.py py2app` I'm getting the following stacktrace and my `dist` folder is empty. Here's the github repo: https://github.com/jonathanmetz/max-exe-example

`lilcrawford:max-exe-example Jonnymetz$ python setup.py py2app
running py2app
creating /Users/Jonnymetz/github/max-exe-example/build
creating /Users/Jonnymetz/github/max-exe-example/build/bdist.macosx-10.7-x86_64
creating /Users/Jonnymetz/github/max-exe-example/build/bdist.macosx-10.7-x86_64/python3.6-standalone
creating /Users/Jonnymetz/github/max-exe-example/build/bdist.macosx-10.7-x86_64/python3.6-standalone/app
creating /Users/Jonnymetz/github/max-exe-example/build/bdist.macosx-10.7-x86_64/python3.6-standalone/app/collect
creating /Users/Jonnymetz/github/max-exe-example/build/bdist.macosx-10.7-x86_64/python3.6-standalone/app/temp
creating /Users/Jonnymetz/github/max-exe-example/dist
creating build/bdist.macosx-10.7-x86_64/python3.6-standalone/app/lib-dynload
creating build/bdist.macosx-10.7-x86_64/python3.6-standalone/app/Frameworks
--- Skipping recipe PIL ---
*** using recipe: ctypes ***
--- Skipping recipe PIL ---
--- Skipping recipe docutils ---
*** using recipe: ftplib ***
--- Skipping recipe PIL ---
--- Skipping recipe docutils ---
*** using recipe: importlib ***
--- Skipping recipe PIL ---
--- Skipping recipe docutils ---
--- Skipping recipe lxml ---
--- Skipping recipe matplotlib ---
*** using recipe: mimetypes ***
--- Skipping recipe PIL ---
--- Skipping recipe docutils ---
--- Skipping recipe lxml ---
--- Skipping recipe matplotlib ---
--- Skipping recipe numpy ---
*** using recipe: os_module ***
--- Skipping recipe PIL ---
--- Skipping recipe docutils ---
--- Skipping recipe lxml ---
--- Skipping recipe matplotlib ---
--- Skipping recipe numpy ---
*** using recipe: pydoc ***
--- Skipping recipe PIL ---
--- Skipping recipe docutils ---
--- Skipping recipe lxml ---
--- Skipping recipe matplotlib ---
--- Skipping recipe numpy ---
--- Skipping recipe pyenchant ---
--- Skipping recipe pygame ---
--- Skipping recipe pyopengl ---
--- Skipping recipe pyside ---
--- Skipping recipe pyzmq ---
--- Skipping recipe qt5 ---
*** using recipe: re ***
--- Skipping recipe PIL ---
--- Skipping recipe docutils ---
--- Skipping recipe lxml ---
--- Skipping recipe matplotlib ---
--- Skipping recipe numpy ---
--- Skipping recipe pyenchant ---
--- Skipping recipe pygame ---
--- Skipping recipe pyopengl ---
--- Skipping recipe pyside ---
--- Skipping recipe pyzmq ---
--- Skipping recipe qt5 ---
--- Skipping recipe scipy ---
*** using recipe: setuptools ***
--- Skipping recipe PIL ---
--- Skipping recipe docutils ---
--- Skipping recipe lxml ---
--- Skipping recipe matplotlib ---
--- Skipping recipe numpy ---
--- Skipping recipe pyenchant ---
--- Skipping recipe pygame ---
--- Skipping recipe pyopengl ---
--- Skipping recipe pyside ---
--- Skipping recipe pyzmq ---
--- Skipping recipe qt5 ---
--- Skipping recipe scipy ---
Segmentation fault: 11
lilcrawford:max-exe-example Jonnymetz$`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`py2app` appears to be incompatible with Python 3.6